# Both custom and original markers are showing google maps api v3

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

For some reason I have both markers showing.. http://picpaste.com/Screen_Shot_2013-10-02_at_10.55.41_AM-qKfxgyCO.png

There's also a box surrounding the whole thing. Any ideas why these would be showing up?

```
var gmap;

function initialize() {

  var myLat = new google.maps.LatLng(33.991447,-84.09403);

  var mapOptions = {
    zoom: 13,
    center: myLat,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  };

  var gmap = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), mapOptions);

  var mapIcon = '../fw/img/map-marker-lowres.png';

  var infowindowContent ='<div class="mapbox"><p><strong>The Arena at Gwinnett Center</strong></p>' + '<p>6400 Sugarloaf Pkwy<br>Duluth, GA 30097<br>(770) 813-7500</p>' + '<a href="http://goo.gl/maps/g3cs0">> get driving directions</a></div>';

  var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
    content: infowindowContent,
    maxWidth: 250,

  });

  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: myLat,
    icon: mapIcon,
    map: gmap
  });

      marker.setMap(gmap);
      infowindow.open(gmap,marker);

}
```

Comment: The code you posted doesn't exhibit the problem.

Comment: @geocodezip what else do you want to see? html and css?

Comment: If you would like help you need to post enough code (javascript/HTML/css) to reproduce the problem.  A fiddle or a link to a live map that exhibits the problem would also work, as long as you posted the code that you _thought_ was important (which you did).  To me, it seems like you are having css issues.

Comment: This is what I see if I use the code you have posted (modified to replace the icon, which you didn't provide): http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_SO_simpleMap_IconsIssue.html

Comment: When you say "both markers showing" are you asking about [Markers](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/markers) or the [InfoWindow](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/infowindows). I only see one of each in your picture.

Comment: Isnt' it [the second time](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19055087/infowindow-and-marker-not-lining-up) you post this question? As commented last time, it has something to do with your styling of the infowindow, which somehow breaks the default styling.

Comment: @geocodezip thanks for your efforts. Sorry I wasn't clear. I'm just trying to get the infowindow to look how it is designed. Like in the picture, I'd like to take off the white box around it and have everything line up. I'm trying to target it with css and jquery and can't get it to look right

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The general answer (now that you have asked the right question) is that the standard InfoWindow can't be styled the way you want.  You need to use a third party library like [InfoBubble](http://google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/infobubble/) or [InfoBox](http://google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/infobox/) or create your own custom InfoWindow replacement.